# Is there a method of aligning 2D arrays based on features much like Image Registration

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, image-processing

I have two 2D arrays. One consist of reference data and the other measured data. While the matrices have the same shape the measured data will not be perfectly centered; meaning, the sample may not have been perfectly aligned with the detector. It could be rotated or translated. I would like to align the matrices based on the features much like image registration. I'm hoping someone can point me in the direction of a python package capable of this or let me know if opencv can do this for numpy arrays with arbitrary values that do not fit the mold of a typical .png or .jpg file.

I have aligned images using opencv image registration functions. I have attempted to convert my arrays to images using PIL with the intent being to use the image registration functions within opencv. If needed I can post my sample code but at this point I want to know if there is a package with functions capable of doing this.

Comment: check this link https://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-feature-based-using-opencv-c-python/

Comment: PIL images do not have the same format as for OpenCV. That could be your issue. Numpy arrays are what OpenCV uses. You just need to set the bit-depth properly. Are you arrays floats or integers and in what range.

Comment: My arrays are floats ranging from 2.21058 x 10^-06 up to 2.249066. I'm not exactly sure how many decimal places are important at this point. When I try and use many of the opencv functions on numpy arrays I receive and invalid number of channels error which is why I used PIL to convert the arrays to an image. Setting the bit-depth properly sounds like it'd be a step in the right direction. I'm interested in learning how to do that.